# SDL_Image IMG_Load() says the file format is not supported

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, sdl, sdl-2

I am following a tutorial and I think I have done everything right, but it continues saying "Unsupported image format".

The code:

```
SDL_Texture *LoadTexture(string filePath, SDL_Renderer *renderTarget)
{
    SDL_Texture *texture = nullptr;
    SDL_Surface *surface = IMG_Load(filePath.c_str());

    if (surface == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Error: " << IMG_GetError() << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderTarget, surface);

        if (texture == NULL)
        {
            cout << "Error: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
        }
    }

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return texture;
}
```

The surface stays NULL after it accepts the result of IMG_Load();

Also, my includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
```

And, my initialization:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

int image_flags = IMG_INIT_PNG;

if (IMG_Init(image_flags) != image_flags)
{
    cout << "Error: " << IMG_GetError() << endl;
}
```

Also, in case it matters, I am doing this in Ubuntu and I recently switched from Windows, so I may not be doing something with the libraries correctly.

Edit: If you would ask, I am trying to work with a PNG, so I am not using a format that I haven't initialized

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
```

to

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
```

You are currently using SDL_image (from SDL1) header with SDL2, I think your problem is there. Maybe you will need to install SDL2_image-dev, if it not installed.

Comment: OMG. Stupid mistake. Thank you very much!